# Folding tags about various Tex engines

Tags: feature-request, tagging

I propose the following tag synonyms, where the parentheses show the current number of questions under that tag:

1. [pdftex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/pdftex/synonyms) (10) <- pdflatex (48)
2. [xetex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/xetex/synonyms) (26) <- xelatex (17)
3. [luatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/luatex/synonyms) (7) <- lualatex (4)

My reasoning is that what's important about the tag is the engine behind it, and we already have tags —[latex-general], [plain-tex], [context]— to talk about formats.

Comment: Sounds sensible to me, as we've deliberately avoided 'latex'.

Comment: I'm in favour, but I think we should wait at least a day to see if anyone has any sensible objections.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Would `xecontext` be a valid tag, a synonym for `xetex` or a synonym for `context`?

Comment: @lockstep: I've never seen `xecontext` (is it the name of a shell script?) but if it's Context 2 on Xetex, both `context` and `xetex` are appropriate tags for such questions.  I don't think the chances are high of that tag being created, but according to the scheme above, it could be a synonym for `xetex`.  Likewise with Context 2 on Pdftex: hopefully we don't see `pdfcontext` either!

Comment: @Charles Stewart: XeConTeXt is one of the "engines" offered by the TeXworks editor.

Comment: @lockstep: OK, that seems likely enough to appear.

Comment: The ConTeXt people are always pretty clear: it's just 'ConTeXt'. While TeXworks might have a 'XeConTeXt' drop-down, this is not how the ConTeXt developers look at it.

Comment: Probably anyone using ConTeXt is smart enough to realize that XeConTeXt is merely an abbreviation for using ConTeXt with XeTeX...

Answer (score 3):

Now that a few days have passed, with only positive feedback, and I have conveniently acquired the req. reputation, I've made tag synonym requests to xetex and luatex.  The synonym to pdftex, though, I can't create, because pdflatex has far more qns than pdftex: this will need a moderator action, I think.

Comment: Nope, I can't do this either! I guess we need someone from SO to sort this out. (I've approved the others)

Comment: Ah, I've found it under the 'mod hammer' menu :-) Sorted

Comment: Current;y, the number of posts tagged 'pdftex' is only saying 11, but when you follow through you get the ~60 there should be. I'm therefore hopeful that this has worked! (I've added a synonym as well.)

Comment: A few days ago, @Blake Stacey was awarded the "Taxonomist" badge for `pdflatex`. Now the badge list gives him credit for "No longer available". So I'm quite sure your "mod hammer" has worked.

Comment: @lockstep: Hmm, that's a little confusing, to say the least. I guess we have to accept the occasional awkwardness when carry out any 'tidying up' changes.

Comment: @Joseph: Great, thanks.